# Why is a subrepresentation a *closed* invariant subspace?

Tags: general-topology, representation-theory, topological-vector-spaces

If $(\rho,V)$ is a topological representation of a topological group $G$, we usually say that a subrepresentation consists of a **closed** subspace $U\subset V$ which is $G$-invariant. I don't understand why it has to be closed. If
\begin{align*}
G\times V &\to V\\
(g,v)&\mapsto \rho(g)v
\end{align*}
is continuous, then so is the restriction $G\times U\to U$ even if $U$ is not closed. In other words, if we omit the need for $U$ to be closed, $(\rho,U)$ is still a topological representation. So why we impose this condition?

Comment: The motivation is that closed subspaces allow nice decompositions in infinite dimensions (obviously in finite dimensions all subspaces are closed). If you have a Hilbert space $H$ and a closed subspace $V \subset H$ then $H = V \oplus V^\perp$. If $V$ were not closed this wouldn't be true. For example, suppose $V$ were a dense subspace of $H$ not equal to $H$. Then $V^\perp = 0$ and so clearly $V \oplus V^\perp \neq H$.

Comment: @UtilityMaximiser if you would like, write this as an answer, and I'll gladly accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The motivation is that closed subspaces allow nice decompositions in infinite dimensions (obviously in finite dimensions all subspaces are closed). If you have a Hilbert space $H$ and a closed subspace $V \subset H$ then $H = V \oplus V^\perp$. If $V$ were not closed this wouldn't be true. For example, suppose $V$ were a dense subspace of $H$ not equal to $H$. Then $V^\perp=0$ and so clearly $V \oplus V^\perp \neq H$.

Comment: +1. Just to add: the example of $V$ being a dense subspace of $H$ is not just some hypothetical pathological case invented for the purpose of getting an easy to understand answer: it is actually a natural phenomenon occurring all the time. For instance take $H$ to be the Hilbert space of $L^2$ functions of $G$ itself in the right-regular representation. Then the subspaces $V$ of smooth functions, smooth functions of compact support, real analytic functions, etc sitting inside $H$ are all invariant under the $G$-action and hence examples of dense invariant subspaces.

Comment: Obviously we don't want to count them as subrepresentations or even as *different* represenations, rather a different realizations of the *same* representation which might be useful in different contexts. This notion of 'infinitesimal equivalence' due to Harish-Chandra makes this idea of 'the same' concrete.